# hide textarea field when not in focus

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

I want to create a function that can hide a `<textarea>` field when I click at another place. This means that the `<textarea>` field will hide, and the word(s) inside the `<textarea>` will remain.

You can view an example on the [Mapmarker National Geographic](http://mapmaker.nationalgeographic.org/), by clicking on the text button on the left side, writing a message and then click away from the textarea (see below).
[image: Text button]

Here is my current code:

```css
textarea {
  background-image: none;
}

.textlabel-textarea {
  width: 200px;
  font-size: inherit!important;
  color: inherit!important;
}

.textlabel-text {
  width: auto;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 500px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="textlabel-textarea rows=" 2 "" [hidden]="!tab1"></textarea
    <div class="textlabel-text" [hidden]="!tab2"></div>
```

Comment: Where on that nat-geo page is an example of what you want?

Comment: i not sure i understand question

Comment: @mariocatch left side toolbar label with "T".. select "T" put text anywhere on map.. after u write something and click anywhere on map the textarea field will hide and the text is not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>This cannot be done with plain CSS, instead it requires Javascript.</s>
I utilized jQuery below by simply creating a new `<div>` with the value (contents) of the `<textarea>` when you click outside the `<textarea>`.

```js
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
 $('textarea').hide();
 $('textarea').after("<div class='text'>" + $('textarea').val() + "</div>");
  $(this).unbind("click");
});

$('textarea').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
```

---

### Updated version:

Since OP commented and said it does need to be editable, and only using HTML and CSS, here is a (much less prettier) version that answers the question:

```css
textarea:focus {
  border: 1px solid #A9A9A9;
  background: white;
  resize: both;
}

textarea {
  background: 0;
  border: 0;
  resize: none;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<textarea autofocus></textarea>
```

Comment: thanks for your code... u already done the exactly function i want but the textarea could be edit and the code must be css and html... somebody already give me the right code but the answer has been deleted

Comment: @paan thanks for clarifying. I've added a plain HTML & CSS version that is editable at the end of my answer. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: thanks for your help.. updated version of answer save my day...this code worked for me... thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".draggable").draggable();

$(document).on('blur', 'textarea', function () {
  $(this).parent().draggable( 'disable' );
  $(this).after("<div class='text'>" + $(this).val() + "</div>").remove();
});

$(document).on('click', '.text', function() {
  $(this).parent().draggable( 'enable' );
  $(this).after("<textarea>" + $(this).html() + "</textarea>").remove();
});
```

```css
.draggable {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="1" class="ui-widget-content draggable">
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>

<div id="2" class="ui-widget-content draggable">
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>

<div id="3" class="ui-widget-content draggable">
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```